# Delaying template rendering for authentication check in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ngroute

Angular can cause a big security issue if you have static URL's that lead to content in conjunction with an authentication scheme.  If an unregistered user visits the page, the content will flash on screen for a moment before redirecting to a safe location.  I found this issue, searched extensively, and settled upon the resolve property in $routeConfig.  Unfortunately, no matter what I do, it doesn't work.  Code below:

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'js/partials/dashboard.html', 
    controller:'DashCtrl',
    access: access.user,
    resolve: {
      login: function(authService) {
        var promise = authService.isLoggedIn();
        promise.then(function(data){
        // We're in successfully 
        }).catch(function(err){
            // ew, go away, redirect to login page
            window.location = "login";
        });
      }
    }
});
```

AuthService.isLoggedIn() looks like:

```
isLoggedin : function() {
        return $http.get("users/session_check").then(function(result) {
            if (result.data) {
              if (user == undefined)
              {
                placeholderService.populatePlaceholders();
                user = result.data;
              }
              return result.data;
            } else {
              return $q.reject("Please log in.");
            }
          });
    }
```

No matter what, the view flashes.  I have ng-cloaks on the page, nothing.  I have no idea what else to do, but this has become downright infuriating.

Comment: Maybe I'm not remembering correctly, but I thought that thefunction is supposed to return a promise.  (e.g. put return promise; at the end of the login function in the $routeProvider).

Comment: @mgilson Yep, that was it X_X

Comment: Oh good.  I wasn't confident enough to put it as an answer without trying it :-).  I've put it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you pass to $routeProvider should *return* a promise.  e.g.:

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'js/partials/dashboard.html', 
    controller:'DashCtrl',
    access: access.user,
    resolve: {
      login: function(authService) {
        var promise = authService.isLoggedIn();
        return promise.then(function(data){
            // We're in successfully
            return data;  // This gets injected as "login"
        }).catch(function(err){
            // ew, go away, redirect to login page
            window.location = "login";
        });
      }
    }
});
```

And, if I recall correctly, the value that the promise is fulfolled with ends up being inject-able into the controller as a service (in this case, the `login` service is whatever your promise gets fulfilled with).